# Starting a process not working in my windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, process

I am trying to execute an exe file through c#.net using a process. It fails to execute returning the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No process is associated with this object.
>      at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState(State state)
>      at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState(State state)
>      at System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessHandle(Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)
>      at System.Diagnostics.Process.WaitForExit(Int32 milliseconds)
>      at System.Diagnostics.Process.WaitForExit()
>      at VideoHandlingWinService.VideoHandlingService.ConvertVideoToFlv(String SavePath, String WithOutExt, String InputFile, String spath, Int32 VideoQueueId)
>      at VideoHandlingWinService.VideoHandlingService.VideoHandling(String VideoName, String SavePath, String InputFile, String WithOutExt, String spath, Int32 VideoQueueId, String VideoDescription, Int32 RegisteredUserId, Int32 CategoryId, String VideoTitle)
>      at VideoHandlingWinService.VideoHandlingService.StartHandlingVideo()
>      at VideoHandlingWinService.VideoHandlingService.OnStart(String[] args)

My code to start the process is as follows:

```
Process proc = new Process();
string spath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();

try
{
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = spath + "\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = FilArgs;
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

    proc.Start();

    string StdOutVideo = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string StdErrVideo = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();             
}
catch { }
finally
{
    proc.WaitForExit();
    proc.Close();
}
```

Any one please tell me how to do this within windows service. Also i am **running the windows service as local account** and hope there is no permission issue for the exe.

Comment: You have an empty catch block. Remove it or add some logging in there so you see what is actually going on.

Comment: Maybe it means that your empty catch swallowed an exception and the process was never executed, explaining the error message...

Answer (score 1):

Anyway use `System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe")`

Comment: The exception was due to my path.For windows service i cannot use the root path as it is working outside.Now i got rid of the exception by giving the full physical path for spath.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error happens in

```
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Are you sure ffmpeg is not executed?

According to MSDN

> The WaitForExit()()() overload  is
>   used  to make  the current  thread
>   wait until the associated process
>   terminates. This method instructs the
>   Process  component to wait an infinite
>   amount of time for the process and
>   event handlers to exit.

and my guess is by the time you are in `finally`() ffmpeg has already exited.

Comment: put proc.WaitForExit(); proc.Close(); after proc.start() and check what hppens

Comment: The exception was due to my path.For windows service i cannot use the root path as it is working outside.Now i got rid of the exception by giving the full physical path for spath.